# How to forword firefox running in vagrant machine to local machine?

Tags: linux, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I am running django project openstack on virtual box. `./run_tests.sh --runserver 0.0.0.0:808`. This is responsible to start django project. This is running inside virtual-box, which is created by Vagrant. I want to access this result into my firefox running on the same machine, outside of vagrant. 
When I run firefox in virtaul box it gives

`Error: no display specified`

How I will do that, please check **Vagrantfile**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "centos7"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
    #config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: 'wlo1'
    config.vm.network :"private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8080, host: 8080
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 5000, host: 5000
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8000, host: 8000
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 9000, host: 9000
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 9696, host: 9696
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8774, host: 8774
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 35357, host: 35357
    config.ssh.forward_x11 = true
    config.ssh.insert_key = false

   config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #  vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
     vb.memory = 3072
     vb.cpus = 2
   end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Define a Vagrant Push strategy for pushing to Atlas. Other push strategies
  # such as FTP and Heroku are also available. See the documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html for more information.
  # config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
  #   push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   sudo apt-get update
  #   sudo apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL
end
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Alik thanks for replay..

Comment: @Alik  No I am trying, but got some hint like we require `x display manager` something like

Comment: I am not clear : you want to start firefox from the vm and display on your normal screen ? this is possible but why is not enough to run your host firefox to access the vm server and the pages from the vm ?

Comment: @FredericHenriy yes,  " run your host firefox to access the vm server and the pages from the vm" How i will do..

Comment: Are you accessing the virtual machine using `ssh`? If so, make sure you use `ssh -X` or `ssh -Y` in Linux or OS X.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run graphical programs from your vm and forward to your host, its possible. I believe there are different ways but this is what I am using.

1. Install a X11 program on your host. On mac, you can install xquartz (http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/), on windows I am pretty sure there are equivalent but I am not familiar
2. configure your vm to do x forwarding, add the 2 parameters to your Vagrantfile

   ```
   config.ssh.forward_agent = true
   config.ssh.forward_x11 = true
   ```
3. start vagrant and when you execute firefox it will forward to your host

Comment: Thanks for post, On my vagrant machine when I ran `firefox` it gives error ""Error: no display specified" How to remove it, because firefox is neccessary to run to forward result..

Comment: you can try setting the `DISPLAY` variable to localhost:0.0 but I thought vagrant was doing this.